# IAP on IOS app are working in simulator but not on testFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

My IAP are working on simulator but not on testFlight. I didn't Configure tax and banking information, do you think this could be the reseaon why ? Or is there chances that it is error in my project or in my code. As you can see in screenshots, IAP are working even in Release mode and i added "In-app purchase" to "signing and capabilities".

here is some informations in my project :

code of my IAP:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import StoreKit

// CategoriesVC is a view controller that manages the display of categories for in-app purchases
class CategoriesVC: UIViewController {
    
    // The payment queue manages in-app purchases and transactions
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
    // An array of SKProduct objects representing available in-app purchase products
    var products = [SKProduct]()
    // The currently selected in-app purchase product
    var selectedProduct: SKProduct?
    
    @IBOutlet var categories: [UIButton]!
    
    // This method is called after the view controller is loaded into memory
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Add a custom gradient background to the view
        addGradientBackground()
        // Request available in-app purchase products from the App Store
        requestProducts()
        // Add a PaymentObserver object to the payment queue to handle transactions
        paymentQueue.add(PaymentObserver())
        // Restore completed transactions to check if the product has been purchased before
        paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
        handleButtons()
    }
    
    func handleButtons(){
        for button in categories {
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
                button.isEnabled = true
                button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }else{
                button.isEnabled = false
                button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                var buttonCurrentTitle = ((button.titleLabel?.text) ?? "") + " (désactivé)"
                button.setTitle(buttonCurrentTitle, for: .normal)
                print(button.titleLabel?.text!)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Add a custom gradient background to the view
    func addGradientBackground() {
        let gradientLayer = CustomGradient()
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
    
    // Request available in-app purchase products from the App Store
    func requestProducts() {
        let productIdentifiers = Set(["categorieAlcohol", "categorieExterieur"])
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    // This method is called when a category button is pressed
    @IBAction func categoryButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Check if in-app purchases are allowed on the device
                guard SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() else { return }
        
        // Get the product identifier of the selected category
        let productIdentifier = products[sender.tag].productIdentifier
        
        // If the selected category has already been purchased, segue to the next view controller
        if checkIfProductIsPurchased(productIdentifier: productIdentifier) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToBeforeGame", sender: self)
        }
        // Otherwise, save the selected product and start the purchase process
        else {
            selectedProduct = products[sender.tag]
            buyProduct(selectedProduct!)
        }
    }
    
    // Start the purchase process for a given in-app purchase product
    func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        paymentQueue.add(payment)
    }
    
    // Check if a given in-app purchase product has already been purchased
    func checkIfProductIsPurchased(productIdentifier: String) -> Bool {
        // Iterate through the transactions and return true if a purchased transaction matches the product identifier
        for transaction in paymentQueue.transactions {
            if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == productIdentifier && transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
                return true
            }
        }
        // Return false if the product has not been purchased before
        return false
    }
}


class PaymentObserver: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKRequestDelegate {
    
    // This method is called when the payment queue is updated
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        // Loop through each transaction in the queue
        for transaction in transactions {
            // Check the state of the transaction
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                // If the transaction is in the "purchasing" state, show a processing message to the user
                showProcessingMessage()
            case .purchased, .restored:
                // If the transaction is in the "purchased" or "restored" state, verify the receipt and unlock the content
                verifyReceipt(for: transaction)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .failed:
                // If the transaction failed, show an error message and finish the transaction
                showErrorMessage()
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    // This method shows a processing message to the user
    func showProcessingMessage() {
        // display a message to the user indicating that the transaction is being processed
    }
    
    // This method shows an error message to the user
    func showErrorMessage() {
        // display an error message here
    }
    
    // Verify the transaction receipt and unlock the content if the receipt is valid
    func verifyReceipt(for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        guard let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else { return }
        
        do {
            let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: receiptURL)
            let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
            
            let request = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: [ "receipt-data" : receiptString ])
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } catch {
            print("Error loading receipt data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    // This method is called when the receipt refresh request receives a response
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
        guard let receiptRefreshRequest = request as? SKReceiptRefreshRequest else { return }
        
        do {
            let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: receiptRefreshRequest.receiptProperties!["receipt-data"] as! URL)
            // Process the receipt data here
            unlockContent()
        } catch {
            print("Error loading receipt data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    // This method unlocks the purchased content
    func unlockContent() {
        // unlock purchased content here
    }
    
}

// This extension implements the SKProductsRequestDelegate protocol
extension CategoriesVC: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    
    // This method is called when the products request receives a response
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        // Set the products array to the products received in the response
        products = response.products
    }
    
}
```

screenshots :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Do you know where could this problem come from ? tell me if you need other informations, thank you !

Comment: You must have tax and banking set up for IAP to function in the App Store (this includes TestFlight). A "release mode build" is not the same as a TestFlight/ App Store build. Those are signed by Apple and run against production endpoints.  A release mode build in Xcode is still signed by your developer cert and runs in the sandbox.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for the response ! Alright so i need to set this up but can i do it for tests and change the tax form when i will create a society ? because i can see the message "After clicking Submit, you will not be able to make any further changes to this form." so i don't know if i have to wait to create the society to do it.

Comment: By "Society" I presume you mean a company?  You should already have your company set up, otherwise you can't have joined the developer program as that company.  If you have a personal developer program then your tax and banking forms need to reflect your personal details; The tax and banking needs to match the legal entity that enrolled in the developer program

Comment: Test Flight, Enterprise, and the App Store are considered production by Apple. So, when you move to Test Flight, have everything setup as if you are releasing... even if Apple appears to be more lenient with approving for Test Flight vs. the final approval.